# Why leetcode c++ sort() gives Compile Error?

Tags: c++, sorting, cmp

I am doing leetcode 406. Queue Reconstruction by Height. I want to sort the vector> first, but when I finish the sort and cmp part and run code, it gives me Compile Error.

```
solution.cpp: In member function reconstructQueue
Line 12: Char 47: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'bool Solution::cmp(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)'
         sort(people.begin(), people.end(), cmp);
                                               ^
```

What should I do to make it work?

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool cmp(pair<int,int> a, pair<int, int> b)
    {
        if(a.first!=b.first) return a.first < b.first;
        else return a.second > b.second;
    }
    vector<vector<int>> reconstructQueue(vector<vector<int>>& people) {

        vector<vector<int>> rlt(people.size());
        sort(people.begin(), people.end(), cmp);
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: The error explains it: you just can't use non-static functions in that context.How to fix that? I don't know. That's ultimately up to you. However, with more context we could probably give you some good advice.

Comment: Recommendation: Write programs for your computer first. A `main` and the whole nine yards. This lets you test and debug in the comfort of your home, coffee shop, or wherever you find most conducive. Won't help you with this problem, but will with the next.

Answer (score 1):

[std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) wants a compare function with this signature:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

and you are passing a *member function* which is not the same.
Solution: pass a lambda, capturing the outside world by reference if you need access to the members of the class while comparing.

```
sort(...,[&](const vector<int>& v1,const vector<int>& v2) -> bool { ... });
```

And second, the sort function requires being passed the two vectors, it can't automatically convert to a `std::pair`.